# Download huge shared file from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking for a way to download every big (168G) archive from Google Drive.
The file has been shared with me, and I only have the link.
Unfortunately, I am currently on a Windows machine, but if needed, I can download it on an external disk through a different machine that runs Ubuntu.